# How to generate random float in Katalon?

Tags: java, katalon-studio

Does anyone knows how to generate random 2 decimal float in Katalon?

I've tried this code but it doesn't work..

```
import java.util.Random as Random

float randFloat(float min, floatmax) {
   Random rand = new Random()
   float result = (rand.nextFloat() * (max - min)) + min
   return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in case you copy that from your code you have typo in function parameters function should look like:

```
float randFloat(float min, float max)
```

also i check your code and it's ok:

```
Random rand = new Random()
float min = 1.123456
float max = 10.568789
float result = (rand.nextFloat() * (max - min)) + min

println result
```

and in console i got:

```
10-29-2018 05:19:57 AM - [START]  - Start action : Statement - println(result)
7.635803
10-29-2018 05:19:57 AM - [END]    - End action : Statement - println(result)
```

to round float to 2 decimal :

```
float result = ((rand.nextFloat() * (max - min)) + min).round(2)
```

and response is:

```
10-29-2018 08:06:21 AM - [START]  - Start action : Statement - println(result)
2.04
10-29-2018 08:06:21 AM - [END]    - End action : Statement - println(result)
```

Comment: also i overlooked 2 decimal condition. in that case command to get result should look like: 

    float result = ((rand.nextFloat() * (max - min)) + min).round(2)